# Unexpected behavior of UDF for random integers with join operation

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

While working on a code that does join on two tables using salting (to overcome skewed data issues) I observed an unexpected behavior from a UDF that creates random integers column in conjunction with join.

If I create the 'salt' column using the rand() method it works as expected but when I use my UDF that generates integers the resulting join has (most of the times) less rows than expected, and the number of rows my vary (depending on the specific random numbers generated).

The following code shows the problem.

```
    import spark.implicits._

    val data1 = Seq(
      (1,0.11,0),
      (1,0.11,1),
      (2,0.12,0),
      (2,0.12,1)
    )

    val data2 = Seq(
      (1,0.1),
      (1,0.2),
      (1,0.3),
      (2,0.4),
      (2,0.5)
    )

    val df1 = data1.toDF("id","val","salt")
    val df2 = data2.toDF("id","val")

    val df2_salted = df2.withColumn("salt", rand() * 2).withColumn("salt", col("salt").cast(IntegerType))

    import scala.util.Random
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
    val randUdf = udf({() => Random.nextInt(2)})
    
    val df2_salted_by_udf = df2.withColumn("salt", randUdf())

    val df_join = df1.join(df2_salted, Seq("id", "salt"), "inner")
    df_join.show()

    val df_join_by_udf = df1.join(df2_salted_by_udf, Seq("id", "salt"), "inner")
    df_join_by_udf.show()
```

The output (in one of the executions I ran) looks like this.
The df_join is (as expected):

````
+---+----+----+---+
| id|salt| val|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   0|0.11|0.1|
|  1|   1|0.11|0.2|
|  1|   1|0.11|0.3|
|  2|   1|0.12|0.4|
|  2|   0|0.12|0.5|
+---+----+----+---+```

but df_join_by_udf  output is:
```+---+----+----+---+
| id|salt| val|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   0|0.11|0.1|
|  1|   0|0.11|0.2|
+---+----+----+---+```

In another run I got the following for df_join_by_udf
```+---+----+----+---+
| id|salt| val|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|  2|   0|0.12|0.4|
+---+----+----+---+
````

etc.

Why is the behavior with my UDF different than the rand() method (which gives the expected join result)

Answer (score 0):

The udf you use is not actually a "real" function; in the sense that it doesn't produce the same output when applied to the same input (which is the *epsilon* value).

to achieve your goal a possible workaround is to force spark to avoid recomputation of salt value. So for example

```
val df3 = df2_salted_by_udf.persist
val df3_join = df1.join(df3, Seq("id", "salt"), "inner")
df3_join.show()
```

should work. In my case for example it returns

```
+---+----+----+---+
| id|salt| val|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   0|0.11|0.1|
|  1|   1|0.11|0.2|
|  1|   0|0.11|0.3|
|  2|   1|0.12|0.4|
|  2|   1|0.12|0.5|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Comment: The output of the UDF indeed would change between runs but whatever it is it will generate a random value of 0 or 1. My question is why given that it generates the (or a) desired output it doesn't do the join correctly. I am not looking for a workaround. rand() * 2 does the work already. I am trying to understand the behavior I see.

Comment: The function is called many times during the join operation (even for the same row) and every time it returns a possible different value

Comment: you are correct that the problem is due to my UDF being non deterministic. Spark's optimizations assume that UDFs are deteministic and hence the observed behavior. The way to resolve it is to use the asNonDeterminitic() method of udf.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some more and some hints I understand that the problem has to do with Spark's assumption that a UDF is a deterministic function in combination with some optimizations it makes in the join execution.

There is an option to tell Spark that a UDF is non deterministic (method [asNondeterministic]1).

So, to fix my code I would change it to

````
    val randUdfAsNonDeterministic = randUdf.asNondeterministic()
    val df2_salted_by_udf = df2.withColumn("salt", randUdfAsNonDeterministic())```

  [1]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.html#asNondeterministic--
````